# Getting raise Value error in implementing nested chart in bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am in new in using bokeh. I am trying to implement nested bar chart in bokeh for testing purpose. Here is my code

```py
def visualEmergence():
    output_file("EmergencyOverview")
    jobemergence=['Access Cards/ FOBs/ Keys','Plumbing','QR Demo Request Type','Demo Request Type','Other','ThisRequestType1']
    jobstatus=['Open','In Progress','Completed']
    graphdata={ 'jobemergence':jobemergence,
                'Open':[4,3,0,4,0,1],
                'In Progress':[2,1,2,4,0,0],
                'Completed':[1,1,1,1,1,0]}

    x=[(jobemergence,jobstatus)for job in jobemergence for stat in jobstatus]
    stackvalue=sum(zip(graphdata['Open'],graphdata['In Progress'],graphdata['Completed']),())
    source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,count=stackvalue))
    plot=figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x),plot_height=250,title='Emergency Request Overview')
    plot.vbar(x='x',top='stackvalue',width=0.9,source=source,line_color="white",fill_color=factor_cmap('x',palette=Spectral6,factors=jobstatus,start=1,end=2))
    plot.y_range.start=0
    plot.x_range.range_padding=0.1
    plot.xaxis.major_label_orientation=1
    plot.xaxis.grid_line_color=None
    show(plot)
```

but I am getting an error after this line

> plot=figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x),plot_height=250,title='Emergency Request Overview'

The error is

```bash
raise ValueError("expected an element of either %s, got %r" % (nice_join(self.type_params), value))
ValueError: expected an element of either Seq(String), Seq(Tuple(String, String)) or Seq(Tuple(String, String, String)), got [(['Access Cards/ FOBs/ Keys', 'Plumbing', 'QR Demo Request Type', 'Demo Request Type', 'Other', 'ThisRequestType1'] ...
```

maybe I am missing something very silly. kindly help me to figure it out.i have followed bokeh's latest documentation for this
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The exception explains exactly what the problem is. The factors must be either:

- *Seq(String)*

  A list of strings: `['foo', 'bar', ...]` for basic bar charts with a list of categories, e.g. "departments"
- *Seq(Tuple(String, String))*

  A list of 2-tuples of strings: `[('A', 'foo'), ('A', 'bar'), ...]` for a bar chart with nested categories, e.g. "departments within divisions"
- *Seq(Tuple(String, String, String))*

  A list of 3-tuples of strings: `[('West', 'A', 'foo'), ('West', 'B', 'bar'), ...]` for bar charts with categories nested two levels, e.g. "departments within divisions within regions"

But your `x` value that you pass to `FactorRange` does not look like any of those things. Here are just the first couple of items in your `x` list

```
[(['Access Cards/ FOBs/ Keys',
   'Plumbing',
   'QR Demo Request Type',
   'Demo Request Type',
   'Other',
   'ThisRequestType1'],
  ['Open', 'In Progress', 'Completed']),
 (['Access Cards/ FOBs/ Keys',
   'Plumbing',
   'QR Demo Request Type',
   'Demo Request Type',
   'Other',
   'ThisRequestType1'],
  ['Open', 'In Progress', 'Completed']), ...]
```

So this is a list of tuples, but the the items in the tuples are further lists, not strings as they must be in order to be valid factors.

It's not really clear to me what exactly it is that you are trying to actually accomplish, so I can't suggest any alternative. But hopefully being able to explicitly compare what you have to what kinds of values are valid will point the way.